# SQL Server 2008 BEGIN TRANSACTION with BEGIN TRY

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, try-catch

When I tried this from php in SQL Server 2014 it worked, but now with SQL Server 2008 is reporting the following error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.
Any ideas why?

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    BEGIN TRY 
      INSERT ... 
      INSERT ...
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
    END CATCH
```

INSERTS are correct. It works if I remove the TRY CATCH.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to move Begin TRANSACTION inside Try block
Below is modified one you can refer

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT...
    INSERT...
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    PRINT 'Error detected, all changes reversed'
END
END CATCH
```